# Determining if a type is a reference type or value type

Tags: vb.net

I've come from a Assembler and C/C++ background, so I understand the concept behind reference types versus value types in vb.net.  Also, I've read [Jon Skeet's article](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/references.html) regarding references and value types and I understand all of that.

My question is:  How can you tell if a given type is a reference type or a value type?

Is it simply that all integral types (ints, floats, etc.) are value types and all classes are reference types?  (If so, where do strings fall?)

---

Question 2 (related):  Is there a way to declare a class as a value class versus a reference class?  For example (using extreme brevity):

```
Public Class MyClass1
    Public Value As Integer
End Class
```

Using this class:

```
    Dim test1 As New MyClass1
    test1.Value = 1

    Dim test2 As MyClass1
    test2 = test1
    test2.Value = 2
```

At the end of this code, the Value in Test1 is 2.  Clearly, MyClass1 is a reference type. But, what is it that causes it to be such and not a value type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general - enums and structs are [value types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx), classes interfaces and delegates are [reference types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx).

As for declaring a class as a value type - this is not possible, but C# structs are very close to classes and *are* value types.

As for VB.NET, I believe the equivalent is the [`Structure`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k69kzbs1.aspx) statement:

> The Structure statement defines a composite value type that you can customize.

Comment: Thanks so much!  I've been struggling to understand this for a while.  The MSDN links help a lot.

Comment: Good answer. Structures in VB.net can also contain code, btw. They just can't save state